# SocketTimeoutException when connect through a proxy with jira rest api

Tags: java, proxy

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxyHost");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "proxyPort");
```

I'm setting my proxy like that , in my project , but I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.ApacheAsyncHttpClient$6.apply(ApacheAsyncHttpClient.java:403)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.ApacheAsyncHttpClient$6.apply(ApacheAsyncHttpClient.java:397)
at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$2.apply(Promises.java:259)
at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$2.apply(Promises.java:256)
at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onFailure(Promises.java:162)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1145)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:150)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:135)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:203)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.setException(SettableFuture.java:68)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$2.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:59)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.timeout(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:351)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:92)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.timeout(AbstractIODispatch.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionTimedOut(BaseIOReactor.java:265)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.timeoutCheck(AbstractIOReactor.java:494)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:215)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:282)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:590)
... 1 more
```

This is my connection code with jira :

```
AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
    try {
        JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI(JiraProperties.getInstance().getJiraUrl()),
                JiraProperties.getInstance().getJiraUsername(), JiraProperties.getInstance().getJiraPassword());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I need to use proxy because I work in a corporation that is working with proxy in a virtual machine of linux , my code is working just fine if I'll not add any proxy and I run it after my windows machine wich don't have the proxy.